# Windows 10: Switch off unwanted key LEDs, Lenovo Thinkpad P1 Gen 2

Tags: keyboard, power-supply, thinkpad

Besides the useful "ThinkLight" switchable keyboard illumination for typing under dark conditions, there are other disturbing white lights directly in the field of vision on my Lenovo [Thinkpad P1 Gen 2](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-p-series-laptops/thinkpad-p1-gen-2-type-20qt-20qu).

These lights are located on the keys <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and on the **power button**.

<kbd>Esc</kbd> is shining if the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is not locked.

<kbd>F1</kbd> is shining if the speaker is off.

<kbd>F4</kbd> is shining if the microphone is off.

<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is shining if the Caps Lock function is toggled on.

The **power button** is shining if the laptop is on and blinking if the laptop is off.

Not directly in the field of view  but also disturbing if you want darkness are

a **white lamp next to the power cable**

- shining if there is a plugged cable that has power

a **big red light on the back of the screen**

- shining if the computer is on and blinking if the computer is off.

How can some or all of these lights be permanently switched off (except for painting or gluing)? The firmware Lenovo Vantage or BIOS do not allow such a modifications. OS Win 10.0.18363

Comment: All of these LEDs are capable of being physically disabled. But are you tech savvy, and are you willing to forgo your warranty?

Comment: On my ThinkPad X1, in normal operation the only light is the power button light. I keep the other functions default and no lights.

Comment: Bit late but hit Fn+Spacebar a bunch of times until the lights go off.

Answer (score -1):

Electrician's tape.  Or some darkly colored tape, if you want some of the light. Tape will not void the warranty, and is something you can remove later if you want to resell the computer.